# OCI: Determine length of text representation of query columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

My goal is to execute a query (SELECT), fetch results and output them *as text*. Query is given as a parameter and can be e.g. `select * from t`.

I use `OCIStmtPrepare` and `OCIStmtExecute`, then I can describe columns of the query by `OCIParamGet` and series of `OCIAttrGet`. Suppose I get `OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE` = 12 (DATE) for one of the columns. Then `OCI_ATTR_DATA_SIZE` = 7 -- this is size of internal DATE representation.

I want to get this DATE as text, with respect to currect NLS settings. For that I use `OCIDefineByPos` with dty = `SQLT_STR`. It works alright, but I also need to supply a buffer for fetching. The question is: *what size of buffer do I need?*

---

Evidently it depends on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. I believe that Oracle knows this value:

```
SQL> create table x as select to_char(sysdate) d from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE                                                                           
----------------------------------------                                        
DD.MM.RR                                                                        

SQL> select data_length from dba_tab_columns where table_name='X';

DATA_LENGTH                                                                     
-----------                                                                     
          8
```

This is the exact length. Only when date format is masked from Oracle (by a function, for example), it uses absolute maximum (?) value of 75:

```
SQL> create or replace function get_date_format return varchar2 is
  2  begin
  3    return 'DD.MM.RR';
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> create table x as select to_char(sysdate,get_date_format) d from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select data_length from dba_tab_columns where table_name='X';

DATA_LENGTH                                                                     
-----------                                                                     
         75
```

All said above applies to NUMBER as well.
So, **is it possible to get length of text representation of a column in OCI?**

Answer (score 1):

The maximum buffer size for any date is 75.  The maximum buffer size for any number is 42.

I hope that helps.

Comment: 42? Fan of Douglas Adams? :)  
Seriously, how did you get it? The same trick with "create table" gave me 40 on 9.2.0.7.  
Anyway, it is waste of memory to allocate maximum size...

Comment: I was the chief technical architect for a project for IBM where we internationalized a product using Oracle for the back end (It used DB2 also) and that was the size that we used.  It was in some Oracle documentation on internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine needed buffer size by calling `OCIAttrGet` for `OCI_ATTR_DISP_SIZE` attribute. It returns 40 for `NUMBER`, 75 for `DATE`, N for `VARCHAR2(N)`. Add 1 byte for Null-termination and you good to go.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, it's better than hardcoding maximum sizes for different datatypes. Still its waste of memory, and I want to get actual size (regarding to NLS parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the trick is that in C, a string is really a pointer to a character array, so you would say `char* mystring = OCIStringPtr(envhp, x);` where x is a pointer to an `OCIString`, which you can get back by connecting with `OCI_OBJECT` set and asking for a `SQLT_VST` instead of an `SQLT_STR`. The actual memory for the string is allocated for you in the global env by OCI behind the scenes.